# How do I reset MathJax settings in IPython?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, sympy, mathjax, jupyter

I wanted to change the formatting of my equations in the IPython notebook (Jupyter) and right clicked on the equation to bring up the MathJax menu.  I selected SVG as the rendering type.  Now, I'm getting raw Latex in the notebook.

Problem is I can't revert the change because I can't find any MathJax output to right click on!  How can I reset the MathJax settings?

I've tried reinstalling MathJax using IPython.external.mathjax, but that didn't work.  I've also tried clearing the MathJax cache from within Safari preferences without luck.

[Update]
I'm noticing I get two messages from MathJax in the bottom corner of my display as it loads.  One is "Loading [MathJax]/extensions/Safe.js", the other is "File failed to load: http://localhost:8888/static/components/MathJax/jax/output/SVG/config.js"

I think that later one must refer to the path in my Anaconda IPython install, but there is no SVG directory at all.

How do I get MathJax to stop looking there?

Comment: MathJax uses a cookie for user preferences. If you clear it, it should reset everything to page/IPython defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a user changes settings via the MathJax context menu, MathJax creates a domain-specific cookie `mjx.menu`. If you remove that cookie, MathJax will revert to the defaults configured by the page.

Comment: I can't confirm that this is the right cookie, but using the nuclear option of clearing "All Website Data" in Safari seems to do the trick.  For some reason, however, Safari isn't showing the MathJax cookie individually.  Perhaps because it's tied to localhost?  I suspect that's a bug in Safari.